# unable to initialize table filter

Tags: iptables

I have a firewall file saved in `/etc/firewall.conf`. Everything is ok, I can use it for `iptables-restore /etc/firewall.conf` with success.

So, starting from this file, I created a PHP script(that runs as a cron) that writes a file called `/etc/dinamic-firewall.conf`; same content as `firewall.conf` with some additions.

The problem is, when I try to `iptables-restore /etc/dinamic-firewall.conf` I always get this error:

```
'ptables-restore v1.4.21: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter
Error occurred at line: 2
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
```

First part of both files is the same

```
# Generated by myfirewall on Thu Nov 20 08:51:01 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:fail2ban-pure-ftpd - [0:0]
:fail2ban-ssh - [0:0]
```

Also, both files have same permissions/owner. So, what's wrong?

Comment: Use the `-t` and `-v` So you have more verbosity. I suspect you need to load the module `iptable_filter`. Check what modules there are availiable `ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/`

Comment: As I said, when using `firewall.conf` no error is returned;
`ls` command returns `iptable_filter.ko`

Comment: Alright, so try `modprobe /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_filter.ko`. Also  specify `<` when using `iptables-restore`

Comment: `modprobe /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_filter.ko` returns 
`modprobe: FATAL: Module /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_filter.ko not found.`

but:
`root@ubuntu:/lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter# ls -l` returns
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7156 Jul 15 07:38 arptable_filter.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7868 Jul 15 07:38 iptable_filter.ko`

Comment: Also, using `<` it's not helping.

Comment: Did you mean to misspell d-y-n-a-m-i-c?  What is the output of `lsmod | grep iptable`?

Comment: `iptable_filter         12810  1
ip_tables              27239  1 iptable_filter
x_tables               34059  7 ip6table_filter,ip_tables,xt_conntrack,xt_multiport,iptable_filter,ipt_REJECT,ip6_tables
`
dinamic = dynamic (native language)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was the line-ending style; instead of `"\r\n"` I used `"\n"` and now everything works.